# How to get the corresponding index shown together with the max value

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, max, pandas-groupby

I have this set of table

```
MonthNum     Trips
1             45000
2             23000
3             78000
4             89000
5             98000
6             96000
7             47000
```

When I run the following code : I get the result of the max but not the corresponding month.
Can I please get some help on this ?

```
*df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
 df = df[['MonthNum','Trips']]
 df = df.groupby('MonthNum').sum().max()
 print(f" The overall busiest month : \n {df}", )*
```

Returns the following : I need to show the month beside the value
The overall busiest month :
Trips    98000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `.idxmax()`:

```py
df = df.groupby("MonthNum", as_index=False).sum()
print(df.loc[df["Trips"].idxmax()])
```

Prints:

```
MonthNum        5
Trips       98000
Name: 4, dtype: int64
```